# is_valid() returns false on nested serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**The code**

Serializers.py:

```
class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Activity

class RouteOrderingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activity = ActivitySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = RouteOrdering
        fields = ('id','activity','day','order','route','activity')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        routeordering = RouteOrdering.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return routeordering
```

a create func:

```
def make(data):
    serializer = RouteOrderingSerializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
```

**The problem**

For some reason, because of the writable nested serializer, the serializer.is_valid() function finds the passed data as not valid and does not let me save the instance.
I have tried also to skip the is_valid() function but of course it is not allowed by the rest framework.

The data **is** on the currect format, and the ORM should accept it.

Any help will be appriciated :)

**Probably worth to note**
When im passing data to create for Routeorderingserializer, I want to pass only an activity_id and not the whole activity object. iv'e tried it with a full activity object too but it didn't help.

Comment: for me, I will add a new `RouteOrderingWriteSerializer` which do not use nested serializer ( comment the `activity = ActivitySerializer() ` line), and in the view, override the `get_serializer_class` method, if `self.action == 'create'`, use the new added `RouteOrderingWriteSerializer`

Comment: Havn't actually thought about that, thank you so much :)